# MacOS Passenger Ruby PG Gem Segmentation Fault

Tags: ruby, macos, segmentation-fault, rvm, passenger

For some reason a segmentation fault keeps my site from even loading the first page.  I've reinstalled rubies, updated gems, reinstalled postgresql and nginx, checked over my nginx.conf file, and perused logs.  Currently I only have one Ruby 2.3.1 installed via RVM, and IRB works like a charm.  Passenger says preloader found an error.

From the looks of it, it's using Ruby 2.0.0p648 interpreter but 2.3.1 is the only version installed.  Can I change that somehow?  I've set rvm to use and --default to 2.3.1, and that's what it shows, but it keeps coming back to 2.0.0 somehow.  It seems RVM's settings won't update.  I'm stumped.

```
    An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger. Please read this article for more information about this problem.
    Raw process output:

    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
    ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

    -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
         See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
             * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
             * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
             * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
             * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
         the more detail of.

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
    c:0023 p:-17535534978622 s:0081 e:000080 TOP    [FINISH]
    c:0022 p:---- s:0079 e:000078 CFUNC  :require
    c:0021 p:0009 s:0075 e:000074 TOP    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:4 [FINISH]
    c:0020 p:---- s:0071 e:000070 CFUNC  :require
    c:0019 p:0039 s:0067 e:000066 BLOCK  /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91 [FINISH]
    c:0018 p:---- s:0063 e:000062 CFUNC  :each
    c:0017 p:0055 s:0060 e:000059 BLOCK  /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86 [FINISH]
    c:0016 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :each
    c:0015 p:0032 s:0051 e:000050 METHOD /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75
    c:0014 p:0013 s:0047 e:000046 METHOD /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106
    c:0013 p:0027 s:0043 e:000042 TOP    /Library/WebServer/Documents/HQ/app.rb:7 [FINISH]
    c:0012 p:---- s:0041 e:000040 CFUNC  :require
    c:0011 p:0020 s:0037 e:000036 BLOCK  config.ru:5 [FINISH]
    c:0010 p:---- s:0035 e:000034 CFUNC  :instance_eval
    c:0009 p:0039 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55 [FINISH]
    c:0008 p:---- s:0027 e:000026 CFUNC  :new
    c:0007 p:0013 s:0024 E:0008e8 EVAL   config.ru:1 [FINISH]
    c:0006 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :eval
    c:0005 p:0150 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110
    c:0004 p:0115 s:0009 e:000008 CLASS  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156
    c:0003 p:0011 s:0006 e:000005 CLASS  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30
    c:0002 p:0036 s:0004 E:000448 EVAL   /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29 [FINISH]
    c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000398 TOP    [FINISH]

    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
    /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
    config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    config.ru:1:in `new'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
    config.ru:5:in `require'
    /Library/WebServer/Documents/HQ/app.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/pg-0.19.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require'

    -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

    -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

    * Loaded script: /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb

    * Loaded features:

            0 enumerator.so
            1 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/encdb.bundle
            2 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
            3 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/rbconfig.rb
            4 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
            5 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
            6 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
            7 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
            8 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
            9 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
         10 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
         11 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
         12 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
         13 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
         14 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
         15 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
         16 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
         17 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
         18 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
         19 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
         20 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
         21 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb
         22 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
         23 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/etc.bundle
         24 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
         25 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb
         26 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
         27 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
         28 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
         29 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb
         30 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/binary_compatibility.rb
         31 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/buildout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-universal-macosx/passenger_native_support.bundle
         32 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
         33 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/socket.bundle
         34 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
         35 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/pathname.bundle
         36 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
         37 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
         38 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
         39 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/base64.rb
         40 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
         41 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
         42 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
         43 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
         44 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
         45 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
         46 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
         47 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/fcntl.bundle
         48 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
         49 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
         50 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
         51 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
         52 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
         53 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
         54 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/stringio.bundle
         55 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
         56 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
         57 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
         58 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core/version.rb
         59 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core.rb
         60 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails/version.rb
         61 /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.30_2/libexec/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails.rb
         62 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
         63 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/postit_trampoline.rb
         64 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/constants.rb
         65 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/io/console.bundle
         66 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
         67 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
         68 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
         69 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
         70 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
         71 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/build_error.rb
         72 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb
         73 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/configure_builder.rb
         74 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
         75 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb
         76 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb
         77 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb
         78 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/optparse.rb
         79 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/command.rb
         80 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/cmake_builder.rb
         81 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext.rb
         82 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/errors.rb
         83 /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/environment_preserver.rb
         84 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
         85 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb
         86 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
         87 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
         88 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
         89 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
         90 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
         91 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
         92 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
         93 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
         94 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
         95 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin15/zlib.bundle
         96 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
         97 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/header.rb
         98 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
         99 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/request.rb
        100 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/requests.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your pg gem compiled against 2.0.0p648 when you originally installed it. Simply running

> gem uninstall pg
>
> rvm use ruby_2_3_1 (switch to Ruby 2.3.1)
>
> gem install pg (This should recompile it against Ruby 2.3.1)

Also specify ruby version in passenger config file.

> passenger_ruby         /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby;

Comment: Did the first several times (proper ruby name, btw), and nothing happened.  The latter I tried...but your version, `*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Even Passenger can't see the right RVM version.  `$passenger-config --ruby-command` Has a result of ruby 2.0.0p648 for some reason.  `To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
  Command: /usr/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: passenger is not taking RVM ruby version (2.3.1) and it is taking system ruby version (2.0.0p648).

You have configured RVM ruby for user **rich**, are you running passenger as root user?

Comment: No.   It was a RVM and Passenger issue.  All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't point directly to a hard binary.  RVM needs that pointer to a wrapper, so this is the final path: `passenger_ruby /Users/rich/.rvm/wrappers/default/ruby`, which is a pointer to `passenger_ruby /Users/rich/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1/ruby`.  Tested both applications and it works completely now.  The command `brew info nginx --with-passenger` output the wrong ruby location.